# How to add a Jiggle Bone in Blender Game Engine?

Tags: game-engine, bones, cloth-simulation

Basically, I want to add a jiggle bone in the blender game engine. I have tried to use a jiggle bone method that works in Blender Internal with a cloth simulation, however, when I place that method inside the BGE, it does not play back.

How would I add a jiggle bone inside BGE? Is this because BGE doesn't support any way to make jiggle bones, or that the game engine is not playing back anything?

Comment: what do you mean with "Jiggle Bone"?

Comment: A bone that reacts to movement. Its used for hair, loose mechanics, panels, etc. for characters you control and stuff.

Comment: You can use bone constraints. Be aware not all constraints are supported. This means certain mechanics from Blender will not work in the BGE. Maybe this one helps: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?370349